# Adjust the Bounding Box on new Master shapes

Tags: visio, shapesheet

I want to create custom master shapes in a stencil. Specifically, I'm creating valves similar to those found in Process Engineering > Valves and Fittings

I want the bounding box when you drop the shape to be a perfect square around the center of the valve, similar to the Powered Valve shape. Once I get this to work, it should align properly with other valves.

[image: Image of Comparison]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to **build** your shape from scratch:

- Create a rectangle the size of your intended bounding box.
- Click *Home / Arrange / Group / Convert to Group*
- Open the ShapeSheet of you new group shape and set the [LockCalcWH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff766862.aspx) cell in the Protection section to 1 (this will prevent the bounding box from resizing when geometry sits outside of the intended area.)
  [image: Visio LockCalcWH cell]
- Position your valve shape over the group shape then drag select all of them and a click *Group / Add to Group*

If you're wanting to **modify** the 'wrong' shape from your image, (ie where the alignment box completely encloses all of the sub-shapes / geometry) - then you'll need to change the geometry of sub-shape sizes which are probably defined relative to the size of the outer (group) shape.  If it is already a group shape, you might find it easier to ungroup and then follow the steps above to regroup.

Bear in mind that if you ungroup you will lose any Shape Data and referencing cells defined in the group shape and these will need to be reapplied to the new group.

Comment: I had to tweak this solution a little to make it work. I created the square, set my valve shape inside of the square (making sure that nothing was outside of the square borders), grouped them, set LockCalcWH to 1, then resized my valve as necessary. Finally, to get square to disappear, I carefully clicked on the square within the group until only it was selected and deleted it. The bounding box retained its shape! Thank you!